# New to C++, created something that outputs seemingly infinite numbers. Could someone explain why?

Tags: c++, while-loop

I am new to C++, and wanted to test my knowledge in while loops, I use MS Visual Studios 2019, and created this code

```
int main() {
    int i = 12;
    while (i > 10) {
        cout << i;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, I am met with a seemingly infinite line of numbers that continues to run. I tried using this on w3schools IDE and it prints out a long string. I am aware ints are up to 2,147,483,647 yet it doesnt end there, or even have it in there. Could someone explain to me what happened?

Comment: Firstly, an `int` on *your platform* may be up to `2147483647`.   That is not guaranteed (the upper limit of an `int` is implementation-defined, and the standard only requires that an `int` can represent values to `65535`).   Regardless of what the limit is, consider what happens when an `int` with the maximum value it can represent is *incremented*.   The behaviour of a program doing that operation is *undefined* - there is no guarantee of wrap-around, nor is there a guarantee that your loop will end, no guarantee of anything.

Comment: @Peter the standard only requires an int can represent values up to 32767

Comment: @M.M   Thanks for that.  For some reason I typed in the maximum required value of an `unsigned`.

Comment: Side note: There is no defined maximum value for any of the basic integer types. `int` is defined as being at least 16 bit and no larger then `long`. `long` can be no larger than `long long`. And `'long long` currently has no mandated upper limit.

Comment: @user4581301   True, but it's also a statement that is easily misinterpreted.   I've seen beginners start with a similar statement, and infer that `long long` is an unbounded type.   When it is *actually* a type required by the standard to be able to represent the range `-9223372036854775807` to  `9223372036854775807`,  and it is allowed (not required and certainly not guaranteed) for an implementation to support a `long long` with a larger range of values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may look like a seemingly infinite number of numbers will be printed, but the program has *undefined behavior* due to signed integer overflow:

```cpp
int main() {
    int i = 12;
    while (i > 10) {
        cout << i;
        i++;         // will eventually be INT_MAX + 1 and UB
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Since the program will eventually overflow `i`, the behavior of the whole program is *undefined*.

On many platforms, the loop will go on and eventually `i` will go from `INT_MAX` to `INT_MIN` and then will the loop end (because `INT_MIN` is not `> 10`) - but, it's *undefined*. Don't allow your program to cause signed integer overflows.